# Evaluating bash "&&" exit codes behaviour

Tags: bash, return, return-value

We had a recent experience with bash that even we found a solution, it keeps twisting my mind. How does bash evaluates the `&&` expression in terms of return codes?

Executing this script, that should fail because `myrandomcommand` does not exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "foo"
myrandomcommand
echo "bar"
```

The result is the expected one:

```
~ > bash foo.sh 
foo
foo.sh: line 6: myrandomcommand: command not found
[exited with 127]
~ > echo $?
127
```

But changing slightly the code using the `&&` expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "foo"
myrandomcommand && ls
echo "bar"
```

The `ls` statement is not executed (since the first statement fails and does not evaluate the second statement), but the script behaves very different:

```
~ > bash foo.sh 
foo
foo.sh: line 6: myrandomcommand: command not found
bar                  # ('bar' is printed now)
~ > echo $?
0
```

We found out that using the expression between parenthesis `(myrandomcommand && ls)` it works as expected (like the first example), but I would like to know why.

Comment: [BashFAQ#105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) might be an interesting read for you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can read in the man pages of **bash**:

```
-e   Exit  immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a
     non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the
     command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in
     an if statement, part of a && or || list, or if the command's return value is being
     inverted via !.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.
```

Comment: Also the reason it work in parens, is that the whole subshell fails which counts as one command in the top shell.